# Do I need SSL certificate if just sending users to my site

Tags: facebook, ssl-certificate

I am just linking users to my facebook app after they are sent an app request from users on my site.

No accept of application required just a redirect to the site.

Do I still need an SSL certificate to use this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading an *App on Facebook* requires a SSL certificate. You may want to use the [Send Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) instead.